# jquery bind functions and triggers after ajax call

Tags: ajax, function, jquery, eventtrigger

```
function bindALLFunctions() {
  ..all triggers functions related go here
};


$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: myURL,
        data: { thisParamIdNo: thisIdNo },
        success:    function(data){
                        $(".incContainer").html(data);
                        bindALLFunctions();
        },
        dataType: 'html'
});
```

I am new to ajax and JQuery.
I have the above ajax call in my js-jquery code. **bindALLFunctions();** is used to re-call all the triggers and functions after the ajax call. It works all fine and good as expected. However, I have read somewhere that is better to load something after the initial action is finished, so I have tried to add/edit the following two without any success.
Any ideas?

```
1) ->    $(".incContainer").html(data, function(){
                                          bindALLFunctions(); 
                                        });

2) ->    $(".incContainer").html(data).bindALLFunctions();
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should have a look to the [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) functions. You can set a unique event handler at the beggining of your app and all your loaded ajax code will be automatically binded:

```
$("table").delegate("td", "hover", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
});
```

But if you prefer to use Jquery.ajax call you have to do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: myURL,
        data: { thisParamIdNo: thisIdNo },
        success:    function(data){
                        $(".incContainer").html(data);
                        bindALLFunctions(".incContainer");
        },
        dataType: 'html'
});
```

and transform `bindALLFunctions` as:

```
function bindALLFunctions(selector) {
  ..all triggers functions related go here. Example:
  $('#foo', selector).bind('click', function() {
     alert('User clicked on "foo."');
  });
};
```

that will only bind events "under" the given selector.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial code was fine. The new version does not work because [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function does not have a callback function.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your question just what you intend to ask, but my guess is that you want to know about the [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function. It would let you call your bindALLFunctions after the document was available; just do `$(document).ready(bindALLFunctions)` or `$(document).ready(function() { bindALLFunctions(); })`.