# Function not working after ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery bind functions and triggers after ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764766/jquery-bind-functions-and-triggers-after-ajax-call)

```
    $('.chatr').mouseover(function() {
    $('#'+this.id+" .action").removeClass('dn');
    });
```

The function works when the page is loaded, but when new content in loaded through ajax, the function for the new div are not working

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a delegate:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.chatr', function() {
    $(this).find('.action').removeClass('dn');
});
```

However, in case you have a container for all your `.chatr` elements use the ID of that container instead of `document`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because events are hooked up on page load. The specific `.chatr` element is appended after load so you have to use what's called a delegated event handler. Try this:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.chatr', function() {
    $('#' + this.id + " .action").removeClass('dn');
});
```

Note that you should replace `document` with the closest static parent element which content is being appended to.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery event handlers are bound only to the elements that exist when you execute the code. Elements which are added after that code has executed won't automatically have the event handler bound, even if they meet the criteria for the selector. The solution is [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

```
$(document).on('click', '.chatr', function(e) {
    $('#'+this.id+" .action").removeClass('dn');
});
```

Ideally you'd call the `.on()` function on (and bind the event handler to) the closest static ancestor element (i.e. one that will always exist and will always contain the elements you want to trigger the event for), rather than `document`. Without seeing HTML it's impossible to know which element that should be though.

Answer (score 0):

This wont work on dynamically created elements because the event handler bindig is deleted\not set for newly added elements after the initial page load.

What you can do is to add event listener to the parent element of '.chatr' div, and check via
$(event.target).hasclass('chatr') to determine if event should fire